# EntityManager injection fails in websphere 7.0.0.17 but same works in 7.0.0.0

Tags: nullpointerexception, websphere, entitymanager

I am successfully running an application in websphere 7.0.0.0 but it is failing in websphere 7.0.0.17. I am injecting the entitymanager using @PersistenceContext. 
When I try to use entitymanager it is throwing NullPointerException. But the same code runs successfully in Websphere 7.0.0.0. 
I am using JTA with defined data source in websphere.
My DAO is Stateless bean called from another stateless bean(DAO is Injected here). Both calling SLSB's method and DAO method are running in  Trasaction scope(Transaction.Supported).
I am using openJPA 1.1 (default to websphere 7).

I tried to update the websphere runtime to the latest 7.0.0.23 but no use, still it is throwing Nullpointer exception whenever I am trying to inject Entity Manager.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors in the WAS server logs?

Comment: I am also having an issue with the EntityManager not being injected using @PersistenceContext. I am getting a NPE on a line in my code where I do an em.find(.... , ...); I'm using 7.0.0.23 version of WebSphere instead. Have searched for solutions with no luck.